# how xml code converts to design in android studio

Tags: xml, android-studio

[image: android studio]Since XML is used to store and transport data how exactly the XML code gets convert to android app design in android studio?

Answer (score 0):

In Android, the XML is used to implement UI-related data, and it’s a lightweight markup language that doesn’t make layout heavy. XML only contains tags, while implementing they need to be just invoked.

For more Information, check this [site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-complete-guide-to-learn-xml-for-android-app-development/#:%7E:text=XML%20tags%20define%20the%20data,need%20to%20be%20just%20invoked.)